# Calling functions with parameters using a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, function, dictionary, parameters

I'm making a program which has a main menu that asks the user to input an option and store it in integer `option1`, which is looked up in dictionary `options`. The corresponding function is then run. The following code works if the functions have no parameters:

```
options = {0 : FunctionZero,    # Assign functions to the dictionary
            1 : FunctionOne,
            2 : FunctionTwo,
            3 : FunctionThree}

options[option1]()    # Call the function
```

If the functions have parameters the above code doesn't work as the `()` part assumes the functions have no parameters, but I tried the following, which stores the functions' names and parameters in tuples within the dictionary:

```
options = {0 : (FunctionZero,""),    # FunctionsZero, FunctionOne
            1 : (FunctionOne,""),    # and FunctionTwo have no parameters
            2 : (FunctionTwo,""),
            3 : (FunctionThree,True)}    # FunctionThree has one parameter

if options[option1][1] == "":    # Call the function
    options[option1][0]()
else:
    options[option1][0](options[option1][1])
```

This code seems to work fine, but I was wondering if there's a better way to do this, especially if the functions require several parameters? In other languages like C# I'd probably use a switch or case statement (which is not in Python) and I'm avoiding using `if...elif` statements for this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would do this using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to specify the arguments when the dictionary is created:

```
from functools import partial

options = {0: FunctionZero,   
           1: FunctionOne,    
           2: FunctionTwo,
           3: partial(FunctionThree, True)}
```

Note that this also allows additional parameters to be passed when the function is called (as long as all the functions in the dictionary have the same parameters missing after `partial` has been called):

```
def test(one, two, three=None, four=None):
    ...

def test2(one, two, three=None):
    ...

options = {1: partial(test, 1, three=3, four=4),
           2: partial(test2, 1, three=3)}

...

options[choice](2) # pass the 'two' argument both functions still require
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Btw you're missing a comma in the value of options[2].

Answer (score 9):

Sure. In Python, functions can take positional or keyword arguments. For most functions, arguments can be passed in either way, but that’s not necessarily the case for all functions, so we do need to keep them separate. Positional arguments are in an iterable (often list or tuple), and keyword arguments are in a dictionary from strings to values.

We could then represent each function as a tuple of function, positional arguments, and keyword arguments:

```
options = {
    0: (function_zero, [], {}),
    1: (function_one, [], {}),
    2: (function_two, [], {}),
    3: (function_three, [True], {}),
    4: (function_four, [], {'kwarg': True}),  # takes a keyword argument
}
```

Then you could call them like this:

```
func, args, kwargs = options[option1]
func(*args, **kwargs)
```

But if you’re always going to just pass in a constant, there’s a better way: just create little no-argument wrappers for each function that call the function *how you want it to be called*:

```
options = {
    0: function_zero,
    1: function_one,
    2: function_two,
    3: lambda: function_three(True),
    4: lambda: function_four(kwarg=True),
}
```

Then use your first method:

```
options[option1]()
```

As detailed in jonrsharpe’s answer, you can also use `functools.partial` rather than a `lambda`. As he notes, this has the advantage of being able to append some of your own arguments:

```
options[option1]('hello')  # adds 'hello' to previously-specified arguments
```

If you don’t need this functionality, though, a zero-parameter `lambda` will serve you just fine.

Comment: I like the consistency of representing _all_ of the functions as tuples.

Comment: For representing functions as tuples (1st way you mentioned) and using partial functions (as in @jonrsharpe's answer), is one way preferable to the other?

Comment: @Ruben9922: I personally like the second approach where everything is just a function because it makes the call sites simple, but it's hard to say there's an objective reason to prefer one over the other; they both work fine.

Answer (score 4):

To add to [icktoofay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24581038/3982001), if you want to pass an argument to the lambda just do the following:

```
def printDouble( number ):
    print number * 2

options = {
    1: lambda num: printDouble(num)
}

options[1](4)    #this prints 8
```

By adding the parameter for lambda before the ":" you state that the lambda receives a parameter and it is used then in the function it calls.

Also if you don't want to use lambdas you can use the usual way

```
def printDouble( num ):
    print num * 2

def printHalf( num ):
    print half / 2

functionDictionary = {
    'Double': printDouble,
    'Half'  : printHalf
}

functionDictionary['Double'](2)    #This prints 4
```

Comment: The issue is that the functions in the dictionary take different numbers of arguments. Note that, in the question, `""` signified that the function took no arguments (as opposed to `""` being an argument).