# How can I pass positional arguments to my function object set as a value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a combat sequence for my text-based game where the user is prompted for input, and their input is used to grab a function object from a dictionary. I'm having difficulty passing any positional arguments to the function object.

Here's my code I'm working with:

```
def combat(player, enemy):
    """Our mechanism for combat between the player and the computer."""
    while player.health >= 0 and enemy.health >= 0:

        player_turn = True

        while player_turn:
            player_choice = input("It's your turn! ")
            player.moves.do(player_choice)(enemy)
            player_turn = False

        print("It's the enemy's turn.")
        enemy.do('basic attack')

    if player.health <= 0 and enemy.health > 0:
        print("You lose.")
    else:
        print("You win.")
```

User input is grabbed with the `do()` method.

```
def do(self, ability):
    """Grabs the value of the key, determined by player input."""
    self.moves.get(ability)
```

`moves` is a dictionary we get through initialization. It contains all of the player's moves.

```
class Combatant(object):
    """Base class that subclasses Human and Enemy classes."""
    def __init__(self, health, stamina):
        self.health = health
        self.stamina = stamina
        self.moves = {}
```

Here's one of those moves for context. I'm keeping them fairly simple right now, until I learn more about the problem I'm facing. I plan on passing in more arguments to the methods, eventually.

```
def basic_attack(self, enemy):
    """Attack that does a set amount of damage and costs no stamina."""
    damage = 5
    enemy.health -= damage
```

The `Combatant` class only contains those attributes and the `do` and `add_moves` (which I use to update the contents of the dictionary) methods. I've used this to subclass a couple other classes, which have their own abilities. I'm trying to pass positional arguments to the function object nested in `moves`, and I want to avoid using `if-else` statements (so I can maintain compatibility between my code here and the forms I'm using in Flask). I tried setting a tuple next to the function call for `do`, but it returns this:

```
    File ".\combat_sequence_2.py", line 72, in combat
    player.do(player_choice)(enemy)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I'm trying to base my approach on the feedback the OP received on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580993/calling-functions-with-parameters-using-a-dictionary-in-python), and I haven't had much luck finding any possible answers elsewhere. I'm also trying to take a simpler approach, if possible, before I try to play around with the `functools` module.

Edit:

My `moves` dictionary would look something like this:

```
{'basic attack': basic_attack}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your moves dictionary?

Comment: `dict.get` has the signature `get(key, default=None)` whereby if `key` is not in the dictionary, `default` is returned (`None` by default). So the `player_choice` you are passing in is not in the dictionary. I would advise using `self.moves[ability]` instead as it will give you a more clear error when this happens. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get . You will need to handle when the player passes in a `player_choice` that is not in your `moves` dict.

Comment: @FHTMitchell I forgot to include that. I tried doing that, it returns the same error message. I have a basic parser I plan to use for error handling (part of this exercise is compiling and refactoring our code - Zed Shaw's LP3THW).

Comment: @nmaloof94 Did you actually? Because I'm betting (actually I know) if you change from `self.moves.get(ability)` to `self.moves[ability]` you will get a `KeyError` stating the problem key, not a `TypeError`.

Comment: @nmaloof94 adding to @FHTMichell's answer, you can pass a default value to the get function as `self.moves.get(ability, 'basic_attack')` which will pass on 'basic_attack' instead of the default None.

Comment: @RaunaqJain That is almost certainly not what they want to happen. You'd rather re-ask for a valid input.

Comment: @FHTMitchell True. But I just gave him an example of how to pass a default value. The choice of what is best remains with him.

Comment: @FHTMitchell The `None` isn't coming from a missing dictionary key but rather from the lack of a `return` statement in the function.

Comment: @JaredGoguen ha good point

Comment: @FHTMitchell It was the lack of a `return` statement. But I took your advice and changed the `do` method to `return self.moves[ability` for more detailed feedback.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You simply need to populate moves with the function names as keys and the function as the value, like so:

```
self.moves['basic attack'] = basic_attack
```

Any time you take user input, however, you ought to verify that it is valid. First, you need to add a return statement to `do`:

```
def do(self, ability):
    """Grabs the value of the key, determined by player input."""
    return self.moves.get(ability)
```

Then when you call `do`, you need to make sure the return type is not `None` before attempting to call it:

```
    player_choice = input("It's your turn! ")
    move = player.moves.do(player_choice.strip())
    if move is not None:
        move(enemy)
        player_turn = False
```

Also note that the return value of `input` has a newline character at the end, so I added a call to `.strip()`

Comment: I still don't understand the use of `get` when it's not necessary. use `[ability]` and catch the `KeyError`. Much more pythonic.

Comment: In your own programming, you are free to do so, `get()` is, however, a part of the language, and perfectly valid

Comment: The most obvious error, however, which no one else has pointed out is that `do()` has no `return` statement

Comment: You're right about the `return`. I still think the unnecessary masking of an error doesn't help with debugging though. This isn't java.

Answer (score 0):

The `do` function is missing a `return` statement. Additionally, it does not make sense for a function named `do` to not do anything. More so, the name `do` is not informative even if it did something.

Also, I don't think it makes sense for each instance of the `Combatant` class to contain a registry of the valid moves. This seems like something that should be handled on the class level.

The following code addresses these points with an added decorator `define_move` and a metaclass to handle registering moves with the class.

```
def define_move(function):
    function._move = True
    return function


class CombatantMeta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace):
        combatant_class = super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace)
        combatant_class.moves = {
            name: function for name, function in namespace.items()
            if hasattr(function, '_move')
        }
        return combatant_class


class Combatant(metaclass=CombatantMeta):
    def __init__(self, health, stamina):
        self.health = health
        self.stamina = stamina

    @classmethod
    def is_valid_move(cls, name):
        return name in cls.moves

    def perform_move(self, name, enemy):
        self.moves[name](self, enemy)

    @define_move
    def basic_attack(self, enemy):
        enemy.health -= 5
```

Here, the names of the moves will always be identical to the given name of the function - this should help with readability. The use of a metaclass may seem like over-engineering, but this is the only way to dynamically update a class attribute on creation.

The additional method `is_valid_move` will help simplify your main function. Together with an addition function `input_move`, `combat` can be stream-lined to only contain the salient logic.

```
def input_move(msg):
    move = ''
    while not Combatant.is_valid_move(move):
       move = input(msg)
    return move


def combat(player, enemy):
    while player.health > 0 and enemy.health > 0:
        player_move = input_move("It's your turn! ")      
        player.perform_move(player_move, enemy)

        print("It's the enemy's turn.")
        enemy.perform_move('basic_attack', player)

    if player.health <= 0 and enemy.health > 0:
        print("You lose.")

    else:
        print("You win.")
```

Comment: This actually addresses something I was going to focus on once I got past this problem, although I'm not knowledgeable enough yet to where I would've come to your conclusion. Thank you so much! I'll study this.