# Using a dictionary of functions with variable number of arguments - can I use partial here?

Tags: python

If I have a dictionary of functions like:

```py
func_dict = {
    "sum": lambda x, y: x + y,
    "multiply": lambda x, y: x * y,
    "double": lambda x: x*2
}

func_dict["sum"](1, 2)
# outputs 3

# cannot do
[func_dict[i](x, y) for i in list_of_funcs_to_run]
```

which each take similar but slightly variable numbers of arguments, I gather (from e.g.[here][1]) that I could use `functools.partial` to define the dictionary as:

```py
y = 1 # or whatever
func_dict = {
    "sum": partial(lambda x, y: x + y, y=y),
    "multiply": partial(lambda x, y: x * y, y=y),
    "double": lambda x: x*2
}

func_dict["sum"](1)
# outputs 3

# now can do
[func_dict[i](x) for i in list_of_funcs_to_run]
```

I have a situation now where 1) there are multiple `x`s and `y`s stored in a list (such that I could run `[sum(i,j) for i,j in zip(x,y)]`) and but I don't necessarily know the values when the dictionaries are instantiated (e.g. the function dictionaries might be class attributes, and I need to call the dictionary in a class method after formulating the `x` and `y` lists).

Is there a way I could still use `partial` here (or another method) to keep the dictionary of variable arguments and call all functions in one swoop like `[func_dict[i](x) for i in list_of_funcs_to_run]`? I can only think of declaring the function dictionary every single time I create a new `x` and `y` variable, e.g.

```py
for i in list_of_funcs_to_run:
   x = ...
   y = ... 
   func_dict = ... # define func_dict with partials here
   [func_dict[i](x) for i in list_of_funcs_to_run]
```

Thanks!
[1]: [Calling functions with parameters using a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580993/calling-functions-with-parameters-using-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... You have a list of `(x, y)` pairs (or rather, multiple such lists). Is the motivation for `partial` to "lock in" a fixed `y`, or are you just looking to run all the functions on the whole list, ignoring the `y` for functions that don't need it?

Comment: You could just add an unused parameter to the "double" lambda so that all your lambdas accept two arguments? `"double": lambda x, _: x*2`

Comment: @CrazyChucky Yes, I have multiple `(x,y)` pairs, and I wondered if there was a clean way of calling multiple functions for each pair, without having to write out all the functions separately. Putting the functions in a dictionary was one way, but I wanted to also account for the variable number of arguments. Does that make sense?

Comment: @IainShelvington I could, but I think that that might obfuscate certain functions (in real life cases where the function doesn't make sense to take an argument `y`). Just wondered if there was a cleaner way than calling each function separately for each `x,y` pair

Comment: Adding an unused parameter to a function is "cleaner" than generating partial functions in a loop IMO

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, I'd agree with that too. Thanks.

Comment: And `_` is the conventional choice for a "throwaway" variable that won't be used.

Comment: @IainShelvington I would recommend posting your suggestion as an answer, as it really does seem like the best solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than dynamically creating partial functions you can instead make all of the lambdas/functions accept the same number of arguments to fix your first use-case.

```
func_dict = {
    "sum": lambda x, y: x + y,
    "multiply": lambda x, y: x * y,
    "double": lambda x, _: x*2
}
```

We add an unused second argument to the "double" lambda. Using `_` as a parameter name is convention for unused/ignored arguments