# calling functions from python dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, if-statement

How to call multiple functions based on the input values. We can implement this with dictionary without using if-else by below:

```
def fun1(a, b, c) :
 ....
def fun2() :
 ....
def fun3() :
.....


dict{1 : fun1,
     2 : fun2,
     3 : fun3}

dict[1](input arguments)
```

But if the input parameters of different functions are different how can we pass input parameters without if-else. The idea of this approach is to avoid conditions and directly call functions based on input values.

Comment: Why not make one function that returns different outputs based on the input parameters (passed as `**kwargs` for example)?

Comment: Please clarify if you are indeed using Python 2. Otherwise remove the tag.

Comment: Try looking at [Calling functions with parameters using a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24580993/16653700).

Comment: In general you wouldn't put functions with different arguments in the same dictionary, precisely because of this problem.

Comment: What is your use case? I'm not sure if a dictionary is the best way to store these functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try *args method

```
def fun1(a, b, c):
    print("1", a, b, c)

def fun2(a):
    print("2", a)

def fun3():
    print("3")

fun_map = {
    1 : fun1,
    2 : fun2,
    3 : fun3
}
```

sample calls

```
inputs = (1,2,3)
fun_map[1](*inputs)
# output: 1 1 2 3

inputs = (1, )
fun_map[2](*inputs)
# output: 2 1

inputs = ()
fun_map[3](*inputs)
# output: 3
```