# Can regex transformations be stored in a dictionary?

Tags: python, regex

I have thousands of lines of text to which I can apply a regex approach. I'm doing it in two steps, but I don't think my second step is possible.

- Step 1: Pick the correct regex pattern from a dictionary
- Step 2: apply the correct transformation **from a dictionary** to create new output

I'm trying to confirm that there is no way to store the transformation instruction in a dictionary.

I can solve the problem differently by having a decode function for each type, and then have a dictionay of decode functions, but I'm curious to know if there's a way to do it like I first attempted (below).

```
text_lines = """
D3/25' 9
U-106.00
T-106.00
CX
PPlayHouse
LSchooling:School Fees
SSchooling:School Fees
EWeek 14
$-38.00
SSchooling:School Fees
EWeek 15
$-19.00
SSchooling:School Fees
EWeek 16
$-38.00
SSchooling:School Fees
$-11.00
"""
dict_regex_patterns = {
    'AccountDefinitions': {
        "D": r'(D)(\d{1,2})/\s*(\d{1,2})\'\s*(\d{1,2})$',
        "S": r'(S)(.+)', 
        "E": r'(E)(.+)', 
        "$": r'($)(.+)',
        ...etc
        },
    'CatDefinitions': {
        "T": r'(T)([+-]?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?)',
        "U": r'(U)(.+)', 
        "C": r'(C)(.+)', 
        "P": r'(P)(.+)', 
        "L": r'(L)(.+)',        },
        ...etc
}

# ------------------this wont work--------------------
dict_decoders = {
      'AccountDefinitions': {
        "D" : '20'+"{:02d}".format(int(source.group(4))) +f"-{source.group(2)}-{source.group(3)}",
        ...etc
        }
}
# ------------------this wont work--------------------


....

current_column_name = None
lines = text_lines.splitlines()
for line in lines:
    # If the line is one character long, consider it as part of the previous line
    if len(line) >= 1:
      current_column_name = line[0]
    regXpatterns = dict_regex[fragmentType]
      try:
        matcher = re.match(regXpatterns[current_column_name], line)
        decoder = re.match(regXpatterns[current_column_name], line)
      except:
        print('Error: No regex pattern defined for field value type ', current_column_name)

      print (matcher)


    if decoded:
        answer = '20'+"{:02d}".format(int(match_date.group(4))) +f"-{match_date.group(2)}-{match_date.group(3)}"
         print (line, ' <-> ', current_transaction['Date'])
```

This is an odd little file format called "QIF" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicken_Interchange_Format) and I want to write my own convertor. Input QIF, output CSV.

For numerous reasons, not least of which is a peculiar implementation of this file format here, I want to create a function that will take a couple of lines of text and convert it to a CSV style set of records.

Input - as above, desired output - as follows:

| D | U | T | C | P | L | S | E | $ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/25' 9 | -106.00 | -106.00 | X | PlayHouse | Schooling:School Fees | Schooling:School Fees | Week 14 | -38.00 |
| 3/25' 9 | -106.00 | -106.00 | X | PlayHouse |  | Schooling:School Fees | EWeek 15 | -19.00 |
| 3/25' 9 | -106.00 | -106.00 | X | PlayHouse |  | Schooling:School Fees | EWeek 16 | -38.00 |
| 3/25' 9 | -106.00 | -106.00 | X | PlayHouse |  | Schooling:School Fees |  | -11.00 |

EDIT #2 - using Quiffen

Produces this:

````
C:\Users\Maxcot>python
Python 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from quiffen import Qif, QifDataType
>>> import os
>>> import decimal
>>> folder = r'C:\Users\Maxcot\Desktop\Files'
>>> sourcefile = os.path.join(folder,'Exported.qif')
>>> qif = Qif.parse(sourcefile, day_first=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\quiffen\core\qif.py", line 195, in parse
    new_category = Category.from_list(sanitised_section_lines)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\quiffen\core\category.py", line 466, in from_list
    raise ValueError(f"Unknown line code: {line_code}")
ValueError: Unknown line code: t
>>>```
````

Comment: It would be helpful to see your expected output for the sample data in your question.

Comment: why do you mix `format` and `f` strings, your code does not run, try it

Comment: none of the lines is 1 char long

Comment: You can't solve the problem the way you are attempting to because the code in `dict_decoders` is evaluated when it is encountered, at which time `source` is not defined`. You *can* "solve the problem differently by having a decode function for each type, and then have a dictionay of decode functions"

Comment: @Nick ... that's exactly what I was thinking, and I assume there's no clever way to "hack it" ? If you make the "an answer" I'll mark it as complete.

Comment: @Maxcot you already have your answer in your question, so it's not worth an actual answer in that regard. I *do* think there are probably ways you can simplify the code, hence my request to see expected output to understand what you're trying to achieve overall.

Comment: Just looking at the wikipedia page, they have records terminated by `^`. Is your `text_lines` variable equivalent to one of those records, and does your complete source have those record terminators in it? Does it also have a header line?

Comment: Have you seen it? https://quiffen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: "Can regex transformations be stored in a dictionary" - yes...? Everything can be stored in a dictionary. Is that really your question, or what is your *actual* question?

Comment: @mkrieger1 you're saying it can be done, Nick says it can't. Let me try re-word my question: Can regex transformations be stored in a dictionary, in a way such that the code is not evaluted when it is defined?

Comment: Are you asking this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205081/is-there-a-way-to-store-a-function-in-a-list-or-dictionary-so-that-when-the-inde

Comment: Yes... but I don't see the solution there.  I see the dictionary of function names, and then retrieving the name of the function, by means of the dictionary key. But the regex code is itself 'the function' stored in the dictionary. It's like the dictionary of funtion pointers there is a mniddle step , when I'm thinking direct function execution.

Comment: Did you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76750359) too? Maybe it's clearer here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580993/calling-functions-with-parameters-using-a-dictionary-in-python - But I'm not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm discovering what is a [*.qif*](https://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/pim/qif-doc/QIF-doc.htm) file but your example shows a string.

> *I'm wanting to write my own convertor. Input QIF Output CSV*

You might need a parser like [`quiffen`](https://github.com/isaacharrisholt/quiffen) instead of a regex approach.

Or, if you're tempted to use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can make a classical [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = (
    (tmp:=pd.read_csv(
        StringIO(text_lines), header=None, sep=r"(?<=^[A-Z$])", engine="python"))
        .assign(transaction=lambda x: x.groupby(0).cumcount().add(1))
        .pivot(index="transaction", columns=0, values=1).pipe(
            lambda x: x.assign(**{c: x[c].ffill() for c in list("DUTCP")})) # op ?
        .rename_axis(columns=None)[tmp[0].unique()]
        # .fillna("") uncomment if needed
)

# df.to_csv("qif.csv", sep=",", index=True) # uncomment to make a `.csv`
```

Output :

```
print(df)

                   D        U        T  C          P                      L                      S        E       $
transaction                                                                                                        
1            3/25' 9  -106.00  -106.00  X  PlayHouse  Schooling:School Fees  Schooling:School Fees  Week 14  -38.00
2            3/25' 9  -106.00  -106.00  X  PlayHouse                    NaN  Schooling:School Fees  Week 15  -19.00
3            3/25' 9  -106.00  -106.00  X  PlayHouse                    NaN  Schooling:School Fees  Week 16  -38.00
4            3/25' 9  -106.00  -106.00  X  PlayHouse                    NaN  Schooling:School Fees      NaN  -11.00
```

Comment: **NB**: If needed, you can replace `StringIO(text_lines)` with `"file.qif"` in the first *chain*.

Comment: Very nice! You might possibly want to `fillna('')`.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I added it as an optional chain ;)

Comment: Haha, there's always another library :) .. love it! But it does not know the code "T"
    raise ValueError(f"Unknown line code: {line_code}")
ValueError: Unknown line code: t

Comment: I've added it to the question, and I am runnng Python 3.11     As I said, this is a peculiar little implementation of QIF.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `quiffen` but seems like your `qif` file is broken. Anyways, the pandas approach works for me (*with the given example*).

Comment: The QIF file is created by Quicken Home and Business I believe. And it appears to just be a weird implementation of QIF - it's not "broken"
But your example solves my problem, thank you. Something new learnt.